# How to use bean without get and set in freemaker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a class like this.

```
 public class User {
   public String username;
   public String age;
}
```

When i use freemarker.

`${user.username!}`

I didn't get anything.

But if I change the class like this

```
   public class User {
        public String username;
        public String age;

        public String getUsername() {
           return username;
        }
   }
```

I can get value.

How to use bean without get and set in freemaker?

Because I have too many class without get and set.

I try lombok but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default freemarker only exposes the JavaBean properties and public methods.

But you can configure the ObjectWrapper to expose all expose public, non-static fields:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_27);
DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder wrapperBuilder = new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_27);
wrapperBuilder.setExposeFields(true);
cfg.setObjectWrapper(wrapperBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes without getters and setters are not standard Java beans. See [the Wikipedia article on Java beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions), which states that by convention,  properties must be accessible using *get*, *set*, *is* methods.

Hence, you should get used to providing these methods in you bean classes.